# celery task routes not working as expected

Tags: python, celery

I am practicing celery and I want to assign my task to a specific queue however it does not work as expected

My **__init__.py**

```
import os
import sys
from celery import Celery

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sys.path.append(CURRENT_DIR)

app = Celery()
app.config_from_object('celery_config')
```

My **celery_config.py**

```
amqp = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
broker_url = amqp
result_backend = amqp

task_routes = ([
    ('import_feed', {'queue': 'queue_import_feed'})
])
```

My **tasks.py**

```
from . import app

@app.task(name='import_feed')
def import_feed():
    pass
```

How I run my worker:

```
celery -A subscriber1.tasks worker -l info
```

My client's `__init__.py` :

```
import os
import sys
from celery import Celery

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sys.path.append(CURRENT_DIR)

app = Celery()
app.config_from_object('celery_config')
```

My client's **celery_config.py**:

```
from kombu.common import Broadcast

amqp = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
BROKER_URL = amqp
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = amqp
```

Then in my client's shell I tried:

```
from publisher import app
result = app.send_task('import_feed')
```

Then my worker got the task?! Which I expect should not because I assigned that to a specific queue. I tried in my client the command below and no task has been received by my worker which I expect to have received instead on the first one

```
result = app.send_task('import_feed', queue='queue_import_feed')
```

Seems like I misunderstood something in the routing part. But what I really want is `import_feed` task to run only if the `queue_import_feed` queue is specified when send a task

Answer (score 12):

You can change the default queue that the worker processes.

`app.send_task('import_feed')` sends the task to `celery` queue.

`app.send_task('import_feed', queue='queue_import_feed')` sends the task to `queue_import_feed` but your worker is only processing tasks in `celery` queue.

To process specific queues, use the `-Q` switch

```
celery -A subscriber1.tasks worker -l info -Q 'queue_import_feed'
```

**Edit**

In order to place a restriction on `send_task` such that a worker reacts to `import_feed` task only when it's published with a queue, you need to override `send_task` on `Celery` and also provide a custom `AMQP` with a `default_queue` set to `None`.

*reactor.py*

```
from celery.app.amqp import AMQP
from celery import Celery

class MyCelery(Celery):
    def send_task(self, name=None, args=None, kwargs=None, **options):
        if 'queue' in options:
            return super(MyCelery, self).send_task(name, args, kwargs, **options)


class MyAMQP(AMQP):
    default_queue = None
```

*celery_config.py*

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

...

task_exchange = Exchange('default', type='direct')
task_create_missing_queues = False

task_queues = [
    Queue('feed_queue', task_exchange, routing_key='feeds'),
]

task_routes = {
    'import_feed': {'queue': 'feed_queue', 'routing_key': 'feeds'}
}
```

*__init__.py*

```
celeree = MyCelery(amqp='reactor.MyAMQP')
```

Comment: Sorry, but that really did not answer the question. I know that it can be done that way though. I just want to make my last statement happen

Comment: Your last statement is asking to have a specific task run only if a queue is specified for it. You want to disable [automatic routing](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-create-missing-queues) so that tasks like this don't get queued up in `celery` queue

Comment: Exactly, what I want is to just run `celery -A subscriber1.tasks worker -l info` not specifying any queue from running a worker and will restrict the `import_feed` task to react when a task is published with the `queue_import_feed` queue. Is it not possible?

Comment: It's possible. You'll need to override the Celery class and provide a custom amqp class or object when creating a celery instance

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't really visualize what you just said sorry

Comment: I put an example under *Edit* in my answer

Comment: Wow thanks! I'll try this later at home. I voted your answer